# Firebase push notification navigate particular page in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Hi I try to navigate the firebase notification to the particular page I am getting error please help to resolve the error.

```
E/flutter (25335): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
```

E/flutter (25335): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
E/flutter (25335): #0      State.context. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:947:9)
E/flutter (25335): #1      State.context (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:953:6)
E/flutter (25335): #2      AppComponentState.initState. (package:ma_mobile/main.dart:189:17)
E/flutter (25335): #3      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1593:10)
E/flutter (25335): #4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (25335): #5      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
E/flutter (25335): #6      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
E/flutter (25335): #7      _PendingEvents.schedule. (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
E/flutter (25335): #8      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (25335): #9      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that you're trying to use the context of your AppComponentState in its initState method. This is generally considered bad practice because the context isn't fully initialized at the time of initState being called.

To deal with this, you can postpone your work until after the component has been mounted by scheduling it in a post-frame callback:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    // Your code here
  });
}
```

Here's an example of how you can handle Firebase notifications:

```
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _firebaseMessaging.configure(
          onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourTargetPage()),
            );
          },
          onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourTargetPage()),
            );
          },
          onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourTargetPage()),
            );
          },
        );
      });
    }
```

This way, you make sure that the context and thus the widget tree are fully initialized and you can safely navigate to different pages.

Also, please remember to handle the state of your page. If your page gets disposed, you should not perform any actions on it. This can be checked with the mounted attribute:

```
if (mounted) {
  // Safe to interact with the state.
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Nowak thanks for your answer but I have some don't I cant able to declare the firebase as you mention above... I declare like these. FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;